Hard stuck on trying to get images to flip back if incorrectly matched with each other
Trying to create a simple card matching game.
The idea is if you select two different cards in this game, they will flip back and you gain a turned used. If the two cards are the same they stay flipped over, you gain a turn used as well as a point.
However, I am not sure if my code is reading or understanding if the cards are the same or not.
Here is my code:
// Set global variables
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
let movesDisplay = document.querySelector('.move-counter');
let toggledCardsArray = [];
let move = 0;
let winCount = 0;
const restart = document.getElementById('restart');

const imagesLinkArray = [
    { id: 1, image: './assets/talisman1.png', newAlt: 'talisman1' },
    { id: 2, image: './assets/talisman2.png', newAlt: 'talisman2' },
    { id: 3, image: './assets/talisman3.png', newAlt: 'talisman3' },
    { id: 4, image: './assets/talisman4.png', newAlt: 'talisman4' },
    { id: 5, image: './assets/talisman5.png', newAlt: 'talisman5' },
    { id: 6, image: './assets/talisman6.png', newAlt: 'talisman6' },
    { id: 7, image: './assets/talisman1.png', newAlt: 'talisman1' },
    { id: 8, image: './assets/talisman2.png', newAlt: 'talisman2' },
    { id: 9, image: './assets/talisman3.png', newAlt: 'talisman3' },
    { id: 10, image: './assets/talisman4.png', newAlt: 'talisman4' },
    { id: 11, image: './assets/talisman5.png', newAlt: 'talisman5' },
    { id: 12, image: './assets/talisman6.png', newAlt: 'talisman6' }
];

// Function to restart the game
const restartGame = () => {
    const toggledCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card.toggled');
    toggledCards.forEach((card) => {
        card.classList.remove('toggled');
    });

    // Shuffle the imagesLinkArray
    imagesLinkArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

    // Reset game state
    toggledCardsArray = [];
    move = 0;
    winCount = 0;
    movesDisplay.innerText = `Turn(s): ${move}`;

    // Update card images
    const allImagesSrc = document.querySelectorAll('.card-img');
    allImagesSrc.forEach((el, index) => {
        el.src = imagesLinkArray[index].image;
        el.alt = imagesLinkArray[index].newAlt;
        el.id = imagesLinkArray[index].id;
    });
};

// Add event listener to restart button
restart.addEventListener('click', restartGame);

// Function to handle card clicks
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        // If the card is already flipped or two cards are already in the array, return
        if (this.classList.contains('toggled') || toggledCardsArray.length === 2) return;

        // Add 'toggled' class and add to toggledCardsArray
        this.classList.add('toggled');
        toggledCardsArray.push(this);

        // Check if two cards are flipped
        if (toggledCardsArray.length === 2) {
            let firstCardSrc = toggledCardsArray[0].querySelector('.card-img')?.src;
            let secondCardSrc = toggledCardsArray[1].querySelector('.card-img')?.src;

            // If cards match
            if (firstCardSrc === secondCardSrc) {
                winCount++;
                toggledCardsArray = []; // Clear the array for the next pair
            } else {
                // If cards do not match, flip them back after a delay
                setTimeout(() => {
                    toggledCardsArray.forEach((card) => {
                        card.classList.remove('toggled');
                    });
                    toggledCardsArray = []; // Reset the array
                }, 500);
            }

            // Increment move count and update display
            move++;
            movesDisplay.innerText = `Turn(s): ${move}`;

            // Check if the player has won
            if (winCount === 6) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(`Congratulations!!! You won the game in ${move} moves.`);
                }, 300);
            }
        }

I have tried to dive deep into Geek4Geeks, since it was following their game similar game that helped me build yet their code and mine don't produce the same effect when cards are flipped.

What DOES happen?  You haven't really told us what the problem is.

The cards just flip over once when clicked on is what happens.
They don’t flip back over if they are in correct or stay flipped if they are correct.

please provide a [mre]. JS only is not enough to debug

Does the toggled class hide the card somehow?

Refer to the below code for reference. Card-flipping behavior was implemented accordingly. Replace your actual images with the correct image paths in the Image array.


const gameBoard = document.getElementById('game-board');
const movesDisplay = document.querySelector('.move-counter');
const restart = document.getElementById('restart');

let toggledCardsArray = [];
let move = 0;
let winCount = 0;

const imagesLinkArray = [{
    id: 1,
    image: './assets/talisman1.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: './assets/talisman2.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: './assets/talisman3.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    image: './assets/talisman4.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman4'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    image: './assets/talisman5.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman5'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    image: './assets/talisman6.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman6'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    image: './assets/talisman1.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman1'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    image: './assets/talisman2.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman2'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    image: './assets/talisman3.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman3'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    image: './assets/talisman4.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman4'
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    image: './assets/talisman5.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman5'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    image: './assets/talisman6.png',
    newAlt: 'talisman6'
  }
];


const shuffleArray = (array) => { // Shuffle images array
  return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
};


const createCards = () => { // Make the cards
  gameBoard.innerHTML = '';
  const shuffledImages = shuffleArray([...imagesLinkArray]);

  shuffledImages.forEach((imgData) => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="card-inner">
                        <div class="card-front">
                            <img class="card-img" src="${imgData.image}" alt="${imgData.newAlt}" id="${imgData.id}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-back"></div>
                    </div>
                `;
    gameBoard.appendChild(card);
  });
};


const restartGame = () => { // Restart if needed
  toggledCardsArray = [];
  move = 0;
  winCount = 0;
  movesDisplay.innerText = `Turn(s): ${move}`;
  createCards();
  addCardClickListeners();
};

const handleCardClick = (card) => { // On click to be fired
  if (card.classList.contains('toggled') || toggledCardsArray.length === 2) return;

  card.classList.add('toggled');
  toggledCardsArray.push(card);

  if (toggledCardsArray.length === 2) {
    const firstCardId = toggledCardsArray[0].querySelector('.card-img').id;
    const secondCardId = toggledCardsArray[1].querySelector('.card-img').id;

    if (firstCardId === secondCardId) {
      winCount++;
      toggledCardsArray = [];

      if (winCount === 6) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(`Congratulations!!! You won the game in ${move} moves.`);
        }, 300);
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        toggledCardsArray.forEach(card => card.classList.remove('toggled'));
        toggledCardsArray = [];
      }, 500);
    }

    move++;
    movesDisplay.innerText = `Turn(s): ${move}`;
  }
};

const addCardClickListeners = () => {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener('click', () => handleCardClick(card));
  });
};
restart.addEventListener('click', restartGame);
restartGame();
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.game-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .card-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card.toggled .card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.no-click {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .card-front,
.card .card-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card .card-front {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .card-back {
  background: #0078d7;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.move-counter {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#restart {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0078d7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Card Matching Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Card Matching Game</h1>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="move-counter">Turn(s): 0</div>
    <button id="restart">Restart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="game-container" id="game-board">
  </div>
</body>

</html>




You changed the card comparison to use .id instead of .src and you changed/made your .id's all different, so you never get a matched indication of cards not flipping back. Just change .id to .src in the two lines that set firstCardSrc and secondCardSrc and your snippet will work just fine.
